# Stripping out characters that aren't a-zA-Z0-9, _ and - from PHP strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to stop out all characters that do NOT match this regex pattern: `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`.

Usually I would do this:

```
preg_replace("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]", "", $var);
```

but obviously this has the oposite effect to what I want. Is there a NOT in regex? How can I get this to strip out any characters that do not match the pattern?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
preg_replace("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]", "", $var);
```

wouldn't even replace those characters, except if the input string is exactly the pattern. By using `[]` as delimiters, they have not the same effect as their would in the expression itself. You could change your delimiter (e.g.: `/`), or add some more brackets in the pattern:

```
preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]/", "", $var);    // this works
preg_replace("[[a-zA-Z0-9_-]]", "", $var);    // this too
```

Now, **to negate a pattern** in `[]`, you use `^` at the beginning:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/", "", $var);
```

You could also have used the insensitive modifier `i` to match both lowercase (`a-z`) and uppercase (`A-Z`):

```
preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_-]/i", "", $var);   // same as above
```

Comment: Well spotted! And nice elaborate answer.

Answer (score 0):

`[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]` should do it for you. Note the `^` inside the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

How about a ^ character in front the characters:

```
preg_replace( '[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]", "", $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a range element of the regular expression, if the first character is `^`, it inverts the range (hence `[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]` matches any character that's not alphanumeric, underscore or dash)

This is true with most types of regular expressions