# How to remove the character "�" on a PHP string variable

Tags: php, encoding

I'm trying to remove from a string variable, a character that appeared between spaces, I used some PHP functions to do it like `str_replace` but nothing happens.

An example below, I show it through var_dump PHP function :

```
string '�I�N�S�E�R�T� �[�d�b�o�]�
```

If anyone can tell me a way to do this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: You need to handle the encoding correctly: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: Learn this ^ and read up on removing characters using regex. Here is a stack overflow link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011640/stripping-out-characters-that-arent-a-za-z0-9-and-from-php-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
$str = '�I�N�S�E�R�T� �[�d�b�o�]�';
$filtered_str = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH)
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/xlcXOLuM). See: [filter-var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and [filter.filters.sanitize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot, was helpful...Just what I need

Comment: @evolquez Probably *not* exactly what you need. You should never end up having a Unicode replacement character � in your text to begin with, if you treat encodings properly (unless explicitly inserted, of course).

Comment: @xylar The matter is that I'm not working with any Unicode character, I only saw an inconsistency with the variable and decided to print it using the function var_dump and saw that each contained space that character.

Answer (score 2):

That is a simple string translation operation ([Demo](http://codepad.org/E4sYOdrG)):

```
$string = '�I�N�S�E�R�T� �[�d�b�o�]�';
echo strtr($string, array('�' => ''));
```

Output:

```
INSERT [dbo]
```

However you might have the problem to actually not knowing which character that is which then would require you to properly obtain the string first. So replacing it in the after would just be the wrong place.

Comment: seems simple, but if you assign the sentence strtr($string, array('�' => '')); to a variable and them print the variable through var_dump you'll see what is the problem.

Comment: I solved it with the function filter_var: $str = '�I�N�S�E�R�T� �[�d�b�o�]�';
$filtered_str = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH)... thanks anyway

Comment: As written in the answer, this is the fix on the wrong end. You need to check why those questionsmarks come in there in the first place. They denote an invalid character. Your filter does remove the symptom, but not the cause.